# Envers not auditing a revision for @ManytoMany+@JoinTable relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard, hibernate-envers

I have a property that is in Class A as following:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "tblTestLabelExclude", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TestId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LabelId"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@AuditJoinTable(name="tblB_AUD")
private List<ClassB> someList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
```

I have also set @Audited annotation in the appropriate fields in Class B which I want to audit. I have a table also created with the appropriate column names that envers generates. However, it's still not auditing this field. It's auditing other fields that cascade to other entities and they are being audited fine.

Has anyone encountered this or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is anything in `ClassA` annotated as audited or is that only in `ClassB`?  Could you update your question to include precisely how you're modifying either `ClassA` or `ClassB` where you believe the join-table relationship should be audited?

Comment: Have you tryied to explicity tell hibernate to audit this relation with @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.AUDITED)